# Conflicting types interchanging void * and HINSTANCE

Tags: c++, winapi, typedef

For my win32 code, I want to do without windows typedefs. Perusing [Windows Data Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types) shows `HINSTANCE` to be a `void *`. As I know MSDN can get out of date, inspecting `shared\wtypes.h` inside of Windows 10 SDK reveals `typedef void *HINSTANCE`.

Compiling the following fails, returning `error: conflicting types in WinMain`:

```
int __stdcall
WinMain(void *instance, void *prev_instance, char *cmd_line , int cmd_show)
{
  return 0;
}
```

I compile with `clang++` and windows headers.

Changing the `void *` to `HINSTANCE` of course fixes the issue. However, why is this the case?

Comment: `#define STRICT 0`.  But clearly you are not yet close to replacing those typedefs.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how did you find that definition. I have:

```
DECLARE_HANDLE(HINSTANCE);
```

where

```
#define DECLARE_HANDLE(name) struct name##__{int unused;}; typedef struct name##__ *name
```

Re: @chriscomment - interesting! Without `STRICT` I can build fine with `void*` instead of `HINSTANCE`.

Comment: Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/enabling-strict

Comment: `HINSTANCE` is defined as `void*` when `STRICT` is not defined, and as `struct HINSTANCE__*` when `STRICT` is defined. The purpose of the `DECLARE_HANDLE()` macro is to make that distinction when declaring all kinds of different handle types.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see. I was not aware of the `STRICT` symbol. I'm assuming it is an added feature to the Windows headers (over the course of Window's history, not necessarily recent), otherwise why would MSDN list out the non-strict typedefs?

Comment: @RyanMcClue See the MSDN page right before the one you linked. [STRICT Compliance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/strict-compliance): "*With STRICT disabled, all handle types generate the same base type. With STRICT enabled, they generate different base types.*".

Comment: @dxiv Thanks, I see that now. It seems more appropriate to me to have that note on the data types page. It's after all the page that terms up when you do a cursory search for a data type.